# simple jquery ? noob here

Tags: php, html, jquery

I'm new to jQuery, but I've figured this much out. The first PHP part works perfect. I can toggle updown without the src toggle code below. I'm trying to change the image source on click. Basicly I have a post and when they click the arrow it changes to a downward arrow and the comments are displayed, and vice versa.

```
<script>

            $(document).ready(function(){
                <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 1; $i++){
                echo '$("#comment'.$i.'").hide();';
                echo '$("#show'.$i.'").click(function(event){';                
                echo '    event.preventDefault();';             
                echo '    $("#comment'.$i.'").toggle("slow");';
                echo '});';    
                }
                ?>
                $("#show1").children("img").toggle(
                function(){ $(this).attr("src", "images/downarrow.png"); },
                function(){ $(this).attr("src", "images/leftarrow.phg"); }
                );

             });
        </script>
```

Comment: What's with the single-iteration PHP loop?

Comment: Honestly, 2 upvotes and a favorite for a question with a bad title and actually no concrete question in the body is beyond me. Please read the tooltip of the vote arrows.

Answer (score 4):

In the last executable line, you typoed. You want:

```
function() { $(this).attr("src", "images/leftarrow.png"); }
```

Comment: I fail to see the difference between the original line and yours.

Comment: @kay OP wrote "phg" instead of "png"